# Replace values based on column counts R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, na

I am trying to calculate the number of hours that a student attempted at the beginning of a semester of college to replace NA values in my data set. I run the following code to find missing values:

```
IR_Data %>%
    filter(is.na(IR_Data$HRS_Sem1Attempted))
```

which generates the following data (I'm only showing the first few columns):

```
      ID TermCode CourseCode Grade GradePoints UGCohort Gender `Race/Ethnicity` Pell  FirstGen
   <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>       <dbl> <chr>    <chr>  <chr>            <lgl> <lgl>   
 1   189   202009        284 W            0    2020     M      White            FALSE FALSE   
 2   189   202009        235 W            0    2020     M      White            FALSE FALSE   
 3   189   202009        304 W            0    2020     M      White            FALSE FALSE   
 4   323   202009          4 B+           3.33 2020     M      Other/Unknown    FALSE TRUE    
 5   323   202009        235 B+          20.0  2020     M      Other/Unknown    FALSE TRUE    
 6   323   202009        159 A           12    2020     M      Other/Unknown    FALSE TRUE    
 7   323   202009        106 A            8    2020     M      Other/Unknown    FALSE TRUE
```

As you can see, for each class the student takes, the ID is repeated. For the case of student 189, we can see that they received a "W" (meaning withdrawal) for each of their three classes. Student 323, however, received a B+, B+, A, and A for their 4 classes.

I want to run a line of code that replaces the NA values in HRS_Sem1Attempted with a count of the ID values multiplied by three (for the course hours). In other words, student 323 would show 4 * 3 = 12 total hours attempted, and someone like student 189 would show 3 * 3 = 9 total hours attempted.

I wrote this to filter by the NA values and group by ID:

```
attempts <- IR_Data %>%
              filter(is.na(IR_Data$HRS_Sem1Attempted)) %>%
              group_by(ID) %>%
              count(ID)
attempts
```

which produces this table for the total classes taken per student ID with a current NA value:

```
      ID     n
   <dbl> <int>
 1   189     3
 2   323     4
 3   638     3
 4   827     4
 5   895     4
 6   909     3
 7  1006     5
 8  1292     5
 9  1490     5
10  1515     3
11  1536     4
12  1720     7
13  1825     3
14  1846     4
15  2233     4
16  2292     3
```

At this point, I really am unsure how to effectively replace the NA values with this calculation. Any help is greatly appreciated!r

Comment: Could you add some usable data (for example your work is based on `IR_Data$HRS_Sem1Attempted` that is missing in your example data, and maybe there are useless columns)  and a clear example of output given the mentioned data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group_by` to group the observations by ID and then `mutate` the number of entries in each ID group into the HRS_Sem1Attempted variable using `n()*3`.

```
dt=read.table(text=text, header=TRUE)
library(dplyr)
dt %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(HRS_Sem1Attempted=n()*3)
dt

     ID TermCode CourseCode Grade GradePoints UGCohort Gender X.Race.Ethnicity. HRS_Sem1Attempted
  <int>    <int>      <int> <fct>       <dbl>    <int> <fct>  <fct>                         <dbl>
1   189   202009        284 W            0        2020 M      White                             9
2   189   202009        235 W            0        2020 M      White                             9
3   189   202009        304 W            0        2020 M      White                             9
4   323   202009          4 B+           3.33     2020 M      Other/Unknown                    12
5   323   202009        235 B+          20        2020 M      Other/Unknown                    12
6   323   202009        159 A           12        2020 M      Other/Unknown                    12
7   323   202009        106 A            8        2020 M      Other/Unknown                    12
```